# PHP - Comparing 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays. `$child` contains a list of product_id's from multiple categories.  `$parent` contains the product_id's from the parent category of the `$child` categories.

- Parent

  - Child
  - Child
  - Child

All `$child` id's should be within the `$parent`.

The parent currently contains 1140 records whereas child contains 1305, so there are 165 child records that should be within the parent.

array_diff shows only 1 record though, what have I done wrong?

```
<?php

  require_once 'app/Mage.php';
  umask(0);
  Mage::app();

  $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
  $sql        = "Select product_id FROM catalog_category_product WHERE (category_id = 16 OR category_id = 17 OR category_id = 18 OR category_id = 20 OR category_id = 21 OR category_id = 22 OR category_id = 23 OR category_id = 24 OR category_id = 25 OR category_id = 63 OR category_id = 64 OR category_id = 65 OR category_id = 66 OR category_id = 67 OR category_id = 68 OR category_id = 876 OR category_id = 877 OR category_id = 878 OR category_id = 879 OR category_id = 880 OR category_id = 883) ORDER BY product_id";
  $rows       = $connection->fetchAll($sql);

  $child = array();

  foreach ($rows as $row) {     
    $child[] = $row['product_id'];      
  }

  echo count($child);

  //print_r($prod);

  $sql        = "Select product_id FROM catalog_category_product WHERE category_id = 10 ORDER BY product_id";
  $rows       = $connection->fetchAll($sql);

  $parent = array();

  foreach ($rows as $row) {     
    $parent[] = $row['product_id'];     
  }

  echo "<br />";
  echo "<br />";
  echo "<br />";
  echo "<br />";

  echo count($parent);

  //print_r($category);

  echo "<br />";
  echo "<br />";
  echo "<br />";
  echo "<br />";

  $add=array_diff($child,$parent);
  //echo count($add);

  print_r($add);

?>
```

Comment: Did you select all child category_ids in sql query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, the `$child` array contains duplicates.  I added a `GROUP BY` clause and 1305 results dropped to 1124.